# Deduplicate Spark Dataframe by Field

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

let's suppose that i have the following spark *data-frame*:

```
 -----------------------
 | geohash | timehash  |
 ----------------------- 
 | x       | y         |
 -----------------------
 | x       | z         |
 -----------------------
 | z       | y         |
```

is it possible to dudeplicate it by the geohash field and collect the result of the second field like this ? :

```
 -----------------------
 | geohash | timehash  |
 ---------------------- 
 | x       | y , z     |
 -----------------------
 | z       | y         |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` and `aggregate` function to achieve this like below

```
df.groupBy("geohash").agg(collect_list("timehash")).alias("timehash").show

//output
+-------+--------+
|geohash|timehash|
+-------+--------+
|      x|  [y, z]|
|      z|     [y]|
+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Converting to RDD as below gives RDD of Row and ensuing issues.

Comment: collect_list returns an array that we have to handle according to our requirements.

Comment: Fine. Just commenting on below

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired result with `aggregateByKey` of `reduceByKey`. I haven't tested my code with the exact data you have provided. However the basic code should be like

```
val geoHashRdd = geoHashDF.map(row ⇒ (row.geohash, row.timehash)).rdd;
val reduceByKey = geoHashRdd.reduceByKey((a , b) => a.concat(b))
```

OR

```
geoHashRdd.aggregateByKey("")({case (aggr , value) => aggr + String.valueOf(value)}, (aggr1, aggr2) => aggr1 + aggr2)
```

Comment: Why would we not use groupByKey here? Given the use case. When should we ever use it then?

Comment: Groupbykey has worse performance Compared to reducebykey. But yes you can use that too.

Comment: Yes I get that. But when should we use it if this is not a suitable use case? That’s the point